# Bootstrap navbar-toggle won't open when clicked

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, togglebutton

For the longest time, I have tried to figure out how to make the bootstrap navbar-toggle work on my webpages. I have tried everything I know and I just can't seem to make it work. Nothing happens when I click on the 'hamburger'.

Can somebody please point out to me what is wrong here? I have attached the code below for my nav section.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
             Brand Logo
            </a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: exactly, ¿what do you want to do? ¿slide some options? edit: forget it, now i understand. i copy - paste the code, and it works, when i click the codebar, the items slide

Comment: probably you dont have the bootstrap js or Jquery included in your web-page.

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, have you linked JQuery and/or the bootstrap JS? You need these linked for the button to work.